# Профилирование Apache

Tags: apache, профилирование

Доброго времени суток.

Как можно определить сколько времени заняли операции с открытия подключения клиентом до выдачи клиенту последнего байта ответа ? (Ну или не обязательно именно это время- мне нужно спрофилировать время затрачиваемое при использовании разных модулей для Apache).
Как вообще можно определить производительность сервера исключив при этом задержки пинга, того что скорость интернета скачет и.т.п.- интересует только время затраченное на сервере на обработку запроса.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нашел такой проект:  
https://github.com/mschout/apache-profiler  
но в нем нет готовой скомпиленной библиотеки **so**, а мне даже компилить нечем.

Comment: Пока в голову пришла такая идея:  
выводить лог апача с меткой микросекунд  
в конце скрипта делать вывод microtime  
Парсить лог и выдачу, сравнивать два времени  

Но мне кажется, что это костыль. Не могу же я быть первым, кто захотел замерить скорость работы модулей апача.